# How to talk about a week in the past?

Tags: time

I face difficulty in explaining a certain date, week that is in the past, how can I phrase my sentence correctly?

For example, say we are in the 4th week of a month and I want to talk about an event that happened in the 1st week of the same month. Can I say put it like this —

> The event happened in the 3rd week back from this.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: [I'm facing, not I face].

Comment: *It happened **during the week three before the current** [one | week]* is probably the best you're gonna get here. Maybe *...the week three **back** from this one*, but I don't like that so much,

Comment: You may not be aware of our sister site: SE English Language Learners. I think this may be more appropriate for this type of question.

Answer (score 8):

Your use isn't very idiomatic.
You can use the adverb **ago**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ago) has

> **ago**
> back in time from the present
> *He left the house over an hour ago.*
> *The dinosaurs died out 65 million years ago.*

For your example:

> The event happened three weeks ago.

This suggests an approximate date to about one week. If you want to be more specific you can say the actual date.

Comment: It's not idiomatic **at all**.

Comment: It's not easy in English to convey exactly what OP seems to have in mind (not a single date, but a ***time-frame*** of 1 specific week in the recent past, identified relative to the present). Maybe *It happened **during the week three before the current one***, but I can't say I like that much. Once it goes earlier than *It happened [during] **last week***, we're in uncharted territory!

Comment: @FumbleFingers the OP already has "in the first week of [the month]". Or perhaps say "between 1st and 5th of [the month]" (if it's a calendar week).

Comment: Yes, but he *also* said (or at least, ***very strongly implied***) that it's just an *example* of a situation where he wants to refer to said "past week" in terms of number of weeks earlier than the *current* week.

Comment: It's probably better to think of *ago* as a postposition that takes a measure phrase specifying a time point as its complement.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - for me 'the week before last' is charted territory.